# Not getting linkup on Ethernet with ESP32 MCU

Tags: ethernet, esp32, rj45

I have an issue regarding ethernet with an ESP32.  I have designed a hardware with an ESP32 and DP83848 phy for ethernet connection.

The problem is I don't get link up from phy.

I am running the [ESP32 example code](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/ethernet/basic) PHY reset pin is 32. This is the log output from the board.  It just stops at Ethernet started:

​> V (2958) tcpip_adapter: check: local, if=2 fn=0x400e24d8

> [0m
>
> V (2958) tcpip_adapter: call api in lwip: ret=0x0, give sem[0m
>
> V (2958) tcpip_adapter: check: remote, if=2 fn=0x400e24d8
>
> [0m
>
> D (2968) event: running post ETH_EVENT:0 with handler 0x400d3a84 on
> loop 0x3ffb4f7c[0m
>
> [0;32mI (2978) eth_example: Ethernet Started[0m

I checked the communication between phy and ESP32, this looks good.  I tried to read the phy register and below was output.  I had used [cyclone](https://www.oryx-embedded.com/products/CycloneTCP) TCP example code for this. The conclusion is that the phy and the ESP32 are communicating:

​

> Initializing DP83848...
>
> PHY reg: 00: 0x3100
>
> PHY reg: 01: 0x7849
>
> PHY reg: 02: 0x2000
>
> PHY reg: 03: 0x5C90 (this is phy address)
>
> PHY reg: 04: 0x01E1
>
> PHY reg: 05: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 06: 0x0004
>
> PHY reg: 07: 0x2001
>
> PHY reg: 08: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 09: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 10: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 11: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 12: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 13: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 14: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 15: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 16: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 17: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 18: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 19: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 20: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 21: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 22: 0x0100
>
> PHY reg: 23: 0x0021
>
> PHY reg: 24: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 25: 0x8021
>
> PHY reg: 26: 0x0904
>
> PHY reg: 27: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 28: 0x0000
>
> PHY reg: 29: 0x6011
>
> PHY reg: 30: 0x003F
>
> PHY reg: 31: 0x0000

Now I have to check between RJ45 jack and PHY.  I actually don't understand what the issue is, but I am sure it is between the  phy and the RJ45 jack.

I have tried the connection with router and PC directly. I also tried using a different LAN cable, but it didn't work

This is the [datasheet](https://www.pranelectronics.com/pdf/Ethernet-Jack/1Port%20with%20magnetic%20LED.pdf) of the RJ45 jack.

Here's the schematic diagram:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the bug, it was oscillator the current lot of oscillator is not good. I just replaced the oscillator from older PCB and this worked.